# footable together with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, footable

I have a footable on a page, it is filled with a ng-repeat, the angular directive which initializes the footable also takes care that whenever there's new data it should redraw the footable:

Directive code:

```
[...]
.directive('footable', [function () {
return {
  restrict: 'C',
  scope: {
    dades: '=dades'
  },
  link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    element.footable();

    $scope.$watchCollection(function () { return $scope.dades }, function () {
      alert("redraw");
      element.trigger('footable_redraw');
    });
  }
}; 
}]);
```

Whenever I add new data from within the controller, the alert('redraw') gets fired and I can see the table correctly displays the new data; But when I remove data, even though the alert gets fired, the table never updates, and keeps displaying the old rows...

**NOTE**: I know this is not the first time this question (or a very similar one indeed) has been asked, I'm also aware that there's a [directive](https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-footable) that claims that can solve the whole integration issue. But it didn't work for me. I've tried almost everything that came up on google searching for footable and angularjs, but I still couldn't solve my issue, which I think should be trivial.

So... any help or comment is welcome

Comment: footable is probably redrawing the table before angular's ng-repeat removes the old DOM elements from the page. Try wrapping element.trigger in a $timeout.

Comment: @user2943490 I will try it, but I doubt so, since even I keep removing items (one by one). It never removes a single one from the view.

Comment: @user2943490 Confirmed that it doesn't work : (
Same effect... adding updates, but removing doesn't have any effect.